# How to convert webkit timestamp of chromium based browsers to unix timestamp (IN C#)?

Tags: c#

I am working on **netscape cookies extractor and reader of chromium based browsers** and when i tried , i **got the value in webkit timestamp** (17 digit value) 13332724148415168 , **need  a mathematical formula or a function to convert webkit timestamp to unix timestamp**.

Comment: This value doesn't appear to be a valid JavaScript timestamp value. Do you know what it represents (seconds/milliseconds/nano-seconds since what epoch)? What is a WebKit Timestamp? Do you know what time this value should represent

Comment: FYI Chromium doesn't use WebKit but Blink (which was forked from WebKit and, incidentally, why Safari is becoming the new IE)

Comment: check this [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-6.0). eg. `var timeStamp = DataTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(time / 1000).ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Answer (score 2):

you can write your own method like the folowing:

```
static long WebKitTimestampToUnixSeconds(long webkitTimestamp)
{
    const long secondsBetween19701601 = 11644473600;    //Number of seconds between 1 Jan 1970 and 1 Jan 1601

    //Divide by million to get seconds from WebKit timestamp and subtract seconds between 1 Jan 1970 and 1 Jan 1601
    return webkitTimestamp / 1000000 - secondsBetween19701601;
}
```

Webkit uses a timestamp of microseconds since 1 Jan 1601 while Unix uses seconds between current date and 1 Jan 1970 then you have to:

1. Convert Webkit timestamp to seconds by dividing it by 1 million
2. Subtract delta seconds between 1 Jan 1970 and 1 Jan 1601 (11644473600)

You can test it here: https://www.epochconverter.com/webkit

Comment: For anyone that needs to convert to webkit epoch, its `(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() + secondsBetween19701601) * 1000000;`